# Which of these DBMS offers the lowest security for SQLI?

Tags: sql-injection, databases

Which of these DBMS offers lowest security for SQLI? Oracle, MYSQL, SQL Server, ProstgreSQL or DB2? Why?

Could you explain to me, why some are more vunerable to SQLI?

Answer (score 4):

All of these database platforms give developers the ability to execute parameterized queries, which is the industry standard for preventing SQL Injection.

Based on this - I would say none are more vulnerable than the others.

Answer (score 3):

SQLi is not about the underlying DBMS but about the application code. Any DBMS will execute commands sent to it because that is what they are designed to do. It's up to the application developers that connect to those DBMS to ensure they are doing it correctly.